# Writing a custom, highly-specialized, special-purpose standard-compliant C++ allocator

Tags: c++, memory-management, allocator

#### Brief Preface

I recognize that there are many nuances and requirements for a standard-compatible allocator.  There are a number of questions here covering a range of topics associated with allocators.  I realize that the requirements set out by the standard are critical to ensuring that the allocator functions correctly in all cases, doesn't leak memory, doesn't cause *undefined-behaviour*, etc. This is particularly true where the allocator is meant to be used (or at least, can be used) in a wide range of use cases, with a variety of underlying types and different standard containers, object sizes, etc.

In contrast, I have a very specific use case where I personally strictly control all of the conditions associated with its use, as I describe in detail below.  Consequently, I believe that what I've done is perfectly acceptable given the highly-specific nature of what I'm trying to implement.

***I'm hoping someone with far more experience and understanding than me can either confirm that the description below is acceptable or point out the problems (and, ideally, how to fix them too).***

## Overview / Specific Requirements

In a nutshell, I'm trying to write an allocator that is to be used within my own code and for a single, specific purpose:

- I need "a few" `std::vector` (probably `uint16_t`), with a fixed (at runtime) number of elements.  I'm benchmarking to determine the best tradeoff of performance/space for the exact integer type[1]
- As noted, the number of elements is always the same, but it depends on some runtime configuration data passed to the application
- The number of vectors is also either fixed or at least bounded.  The exact number is handled by a library providing an implementation of `parallel::for(execution::par_unseq, ...)`
- The vectors are constructed by me (i.e. so I know with certainty that they will always be constructed with N elements)

[1] The value of the vectors are used to conditionally copy a float from one of 2 vectors to a target: `c[i] = rand_vec[i] < threshold ? a[i] : b[i]` where `a, b, c` are contiguous arrays of `float`, `rand_vec` is the `std::vector` I'm trying to figure out here, and `threshold` is a single variable of type `integer_tbd`.  The code compiles as SSE SIMD operations. I do not remember the details of this, but I believe that this requires additional shifting instructions if the ints are smaller than the floats.

On this basis, I've written a very simple allocator, with a single static boost::lockfree::queue as the free-list.  Given that I will construct the vectors myself and they will go out of scope when I'm finished with them, I know with certainty that all calls to alloc::deallocate(T*, size_t) will always return vectors of the same size, so I believe that I can simply push them back onto the queue without worrying about a pointer to a differently-sized allocation being pushed onto the free-list.

As noted in the code below, I've added in runtime tests for both the allocate and deallocate functions for now, while I've been confirming for myself that these situations cannot and will not occur.  Again, I believe it is unquestionably safe to delete these runtime tests.  Although some advice would be appreciated here too -- considering the surrounding code, I think they should be handled adequately by the branch predictor so they don't have a significant runtime cost (although without instrumenting, hard to say for 100% certain).

In a nutshell - as far as I can tell, everything here is completely within my control, completely deterministic in behaviour, and, thus, completely safe.  This is also suggested when running the code under typical conditions -- there are no segfaults, etc.  I haven't yet tried running with sanitizers yet -- I was hoping to get some feedback and guidance before doing so.

I should point out that my code runs 2x faster compared to using `std::allocator` which is at least qualitatively to be expected.

**CR_Vector_Allocator.hpp**

```
class CR_Vector_Allocator {

  using T = CR_Range_t; // probably uint16_t or uint32_t, set elsewhere.

private:
  using free_list_type = boost::lockfree::queue>;

  static free_list_type free_list;

public:
  T* allocate(size_t);
  void deallocate(T* p, size_t) noexcept;

  using value_type = T;
  using pointer = T*;
  using reference = T&;

  template  struct rebind { using other = CR_Vector_Allocator;};
};
```

**CR_Vector_Allocator.cc**

```
CR_Vector_Allocator::T* CR_Vector_Allocator::allocate(size_t n) {

  if (n <= 1)
    throw std::runtime_error("Unexpected number of elements to initialize: " +
                         std::to_string(n));

  T* addr_;
  if (free_list.pop(addr_)) return addr_;

  addr_ = reinterpret_cast<T*>(std::malloc(n * sizeof(T)));
  return addr_;
}

void CR_Vector_Allocator::deallocate(T* p, size_t n) noexcept {
  if (n <= 1) // should never happen. but just in case, I don't want to leak
    free(p);
  else
    free_list.push(p);
}

CR_Vector_Allocator::free_list_type CR_Vector_Allocator::free_list;
```

It is used in the following manner:

```
using CR_Vector_t = std::vector<uint16_t, CR_Vector_Allocator>;

CR_Vector_t Generate_CR_Vector(){

  /* total_parameters is a member of the same class
     as this member function and is defined elsewhere */
  CR_Vector_t cr_vec (total_parameters); 
  std::uniform_int_distribution<uint16_t> dist_;

  /* urng_ is a member variable of type std::mt19937_64 in the class */
  std::generate(cr_vec.begin(), cr_vec.end(), [this, &dist_](){
     return dist_(this->urng_);});
     return cr_vec; 
}

void Prepare_Next_Generation(...){
  /* 
     ... 
  */
  using hpx::parallel::execution::par_unseq;
  hpx::parallel::for_loop_n(par_unseq, 0l, pop_size, [this](int64_t idx){
    auto crossovers = Generate_CR_Vector();
    auto new_parameters = Generate_New_Parameters(/* ... */, std::move(crossovers));
  }
}
```

Any feedback, guidance or rebukes would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!!

Comment: 1. `reinterpret_cast(std::malloc(n * sizeof(T)));` looks like a typo (missing `<T*>`)

2. The allocator should be a class template and it's `value_type = T`. Note that for multiple standard library containers, the behaviour is undefined if `Allocator<T>::value_type != Container<T, Allocator<T>>::value_type`.

Comment: @Xeverous - Thanks for the feedback. 1) You're absolutely right- I was rushing and missed the T* in the cast.  2) Because I am specifically using the allocator in an extremely restricted capacity, I've taken a couple of shortcuts to make things faster and simpler.  Of course, I would certainly have done things differently if this was meant to be used more generally, e.g. making the allocator a class template as you suggest and making it safer to prevent misuse.  However, it's my own codebase so I don't worry about someone else misusing it, and my own use is extremely limited and it works as-is

Comment: I've edited the code to include the missing T* as you correctly noted.  That line now reads `addr_ = reinterpret_cast<T*>(std::malloc(n * sizeof(T)));`

Comment: @ShmuelLevine [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) may be a better place for this question.